# IIS - Placing an application within a route/subdirectory

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

I have an ASP.NET 4.5 application running at the root level of my localhost in IIS 7.5, within which, I have a route defined as `archives`:

```
http://localhost/archives
```

I'm trying to add a WordPress blog at `archives/blog` but can't figure out how to do so. So the URL for the blog should be as follows:

```
http://localhost/archives/blog
```

I tried placing an empty directory within the web application that runs at root level called `archives`, but as soon as I do that, I get an HTTP 403 error regarding directory browsing due to a conflict with the route.

Any idea how I can override the empty directory with the route? Or any other ways I can make the blog to work at the directory level where I want it to?

I've read about `RouteExistingFiles` property, but also hear that once it is set to true, I will also have to define routes for all my static content (CSS, JavaScripts, Images etc).

Thoughts?